# put method in the json object adds value to the first of the jsonobject;

Tags: java, json

Consider following piece of code:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 

json.put("one", 1); 

json.put("two", 2); 

json.put("three", 3);
```

If i print the jsonobject it prints like this

```
{"three":"1","two":"2","one":"1"}
```

But i want like this.

```
{"one":"1","two":"2","three":"3"}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing like an order in JSON. It is an object.

Comment: Could you please tell us which language you are using?

Comment: i 'm using java. for some purpose i want jsonobject to be in the order i put the values in it

Comment: JSONObject is an unordered collection. There's no built-in way to order its keys.

Comment: If you want a fixed order, you can use an array and store your data like this: `[{"name":"one","value":"1"}, {"name":"two","value":"2"}, ...]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation at http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html says:

**A JSONObject is an unordered collection of name/value pairs.**

In other words, properties of an object are accessed by name, not by position and the default serialized form does not guarantee any specific order.

Strict positioning comes only with arrays:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray();

json.put("1");
json.put("2");
json.put("3");

json.toString(); // results in ["1", "2", "3"]
```

---

The easiest workaround to solve your problem is to use the [sortedKeys()](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#sortedKeys()) method and by iterating the JSONObject key by key, produce the JSON string manually in what ever order necessary. Implementing a custom [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) might help also.