# Json format wrongly displayed

Tags: java, json, formatting

I am trying to display a JSon file in the following format. But when i run my program it displays the top part at the bottom. Why is this? am i doing this correctly? Please find picture of output and expected output below code.

Code:

```
public class Student {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = -7;
        int b = 7;
        int k = 103;
        int order = 109;
        int px = 60;
        int py = 76;
        int qx = 101;
        int qy = 42;
        int n = 3;
        int rx = 2;
        int ry = 102;
        int sx = 64;
        int sy = 17;

         JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
         obj.put("name", "JEAN-LUC PALMYRE");
         obj.put("srn", "120299364");


        JSONObject objEcc = new JSONObject();
         objEcc.put("a",a);
         objEcc.put("b",b);
         objEcc.put("k",k);
         objEcc.put("order",order);

         obj.put("ecc", objEcc);

         JSONObject objModk_add = new JSONObject();
         objModk_add.put("x", px);
         objModk_add.put("y", py);

         obj.put("p", objModk_add);

         objModk_add.put("x", qx);
         objModk_add.put("y", qy);

         obj.put("q", objModk_add); 

         objModk_add.put("x", rx);
         objModk_add.put("y", ry);

         obj.put("r", objModk_add); 

         JSONObject objModk_mul = new JSONObject();
         objModk_mul.put("x", px);
         objModk_mul.put("y", py);

         obj.put("p", objModk_mul);


        try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("Jean-LucPalmyre_120299364_CO3326_cw1.json")) 
        {

            file.write(obj.toJSONString());
            file.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.print(obj);

    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Expected output:

[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has something to do with the fact that a `JSONObject` is actually using a Map for its representation, and that the order of values in a Map isn't guaranteed to be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can add a method to your `Student` class that prints or returns it's properties in JSON format.

Something like this:

```
public class Student {

 private String name;
 private String srn;
 private Ecc ecc;
 ...

 public Student(String name, String srn, Ecc ecc ...) {
   this.name = name;
   this.srn = srn;
   this.ecc = ecc;
   ....
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
     JSONObject jsonName = new JSONObject();
     obj.put("name", name);
     JSONObject jsonSrn = new JSONObject();
     obj.put("srn", srn);
     ...

    "{" + 
     jsonName.toJSONString() +
     "," +
     jsonSrn.toJSONString() +
     ... // do the sane with the rest of the properties
     +
     "}"     
 }
}
```

Then, you can just print like this.

```
try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("JeanLucPalmyre_120299364_CO3326_cw1.json")) 
    {
        file.write(new Student("MARK", "000001", new Ecc()...));
        file.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pacane is right. If you use for example `LinkedHashMap`, it would work.

For example this would work...

```
private class OwnJsonObj extends JSONObject {
        OwnJsonObj() {
            super(new LinkedHashMap());
        }
    }
```

You can use this nested class instead of `JSONObject`, it preserves order.
I don't recommend it if you use this object somewhere else, it would make a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Pacane is right, a map does not store objects in the same order as they were added, and JSON objects are stored as maps in java. I can suggest using an array instead of a map as here: [put method in the json object adds value to the first of the jsonobject;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163343/put-method-in-the-json-object-adds-value-to-the-first-of-the-jsonobject)